# How to get a div to fill 100% height of another div

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/eDYDD/

Seen above is a jsfiddle that mostly explains what I'm trying to do. I can't seem to get the `#main_info` to fill the 100% height of `#main`, so the border will fill 100% of the div and you know, look nice. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS unless a parent has a fixed height, you cannot make a child fill 100% of it's height, without some trickery.

1. You can use display table to make the elements behave like a table, ensuring that the child fills out the parent.
2. You can make it so the border-right in your case is visually managed by the parent element, using a background image.
3. You can use JavaScript to maintain the appearance of the two elements.

Which one of these applies to you really depends on your use case. Since your avatar info is simply a border-right at this point, creating  a visual border on `#main_info` is probably the easiest way to go.

Using a table based layout would also solve this nicely, but would require extra markup to ensure that you have a `table` element, a `row` element and a `cell` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning.

```
#main {
    position: relative;
}
#main_info {
height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eDYDD/3/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks):

> Creating equal height columns with CSS is not as easy as it may first seem. This tutorial highlights the display problems that occur with multiple column layouts, and then shows a simple solution that works in all common web browsers. The method shown here is 100% CSS hack-free, image-free and JavaScript-free so it can even be used on the most strictly coded websites.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eDYDD/4/). The other answers miss out the easiest solution, which is to inherit your `min-height` property of the parent element:

```
#main_info {
    width: 20%;
    min-height: inherit;
    border-right: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
```